# Find number of clusters in time series frequency table

Tags: python, time-series, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, frequency

So I want to be able to know how many clusters are in a time series frequency table.

Input would be a date index with the frequency.
The kind of output you would get when using .resample('D').sum()

Input Example:

| Index | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 3 |
| 02-01-2022 | 4 |
| 03-01-2022 | 2 |
| 04-01-2022 | 2 |
| 05-01-2022 | 2 |
| .... | ... |
| 27-01-2022 | 5 |
| 28-01-2022 | 4 |
| 29-01-2022 | 2 |
| 30-01-2022 | 3 |
| 31-01-2022 | 2 |

Assume the dates not shown (... on table) are all frequency 0.
So essentially there is two clusters in the month of January 2022. First cluster is at the beginning of the month and the second cluster is at the end of the month.

Cluster 1 is between date range 01-01-2022 and 05-01-2022.
Cluster 2 is between date range 27-01-2022 and 31-01-2022.

Do you know which clustering algorithm would allow me to get the # of clusters with this type of data?
or is a clustering algorithm even necessary?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You might get better answers on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. Stackoverflow is not intended for such questions.

Comment: I think you don't need any special algorithm. You only need to iterate row by row your whole table.